# Linked tables from ms excell to ms access without locking editing in

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have a lot of ms excel files which are linked to access (as tables). In access have to be done some procedures/analysis. All linked excel files are locked for editing after access is opened. How to setup files to keep:

excel files writable
OR
most of the worksheets in all excel files writable

in case that access file is open?

Comment: If you need to have access to source files, maybe it is possible to copy excel files to special folder before open Access. You can do it with system script.

Comment: I know about this possibility, but all excels (~ 15 files) are larger and to copy to local would spend a lot of time and I haven't rights to create duplicates on server. Generally procedure would run ~50 times per week and for different person. So it have to be user friendly without "tricky" copy on background.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is in its core single-user only.

One method is to copy the Excel files, then link the copies and do the analysis.

Comment: Could be possible to setup share in excel to reach effect as I need?

Comment: Not that I know of. If one user/process has the file open, it is at the most read-only for the next user/process.